# How to diff line ranges in Vim

Tags: vim, vi

I am trying to ascertain if two blocks of code in the same file are identical.  Is there a way to diff two line ranges in Vi/Vim?

Answer (score 4):

I would create two empty buffers (`:vnew`, `:new`), paste the two line ranges in them and `:diffthis` them. You could, for instance, define:

```
:map q :vnew +put!a^M:new +put!b^M:diffthis^M^W<Down>:diffthis^M
```

If you want to compare two line ranges, select and yank them in registers `a` and `b`, respectively, and type `q`. This will split your window vertically, split again the new window horizontally, paste registers `a` and `b` in the two new windows, and diff them.

To simplify a bit you can:

```
:map q y:vnew +put!a^M:new +put!^M:diffthis^M^W<Down>:diffthis^M
```

and the second line range will be the one currently selected in visual mode. It saves a few keystrokes.

Comment: There is also a plugin http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3745 which creates a :Linediff function (which probably does something similar internally)

Comment: I didn't know this one. Looks good and does a better job than my solution, I guess.